# Angular - Parameter 'url' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006) in Angular Service

Tags: angular

In my Angular-11 service, I have this code:

```
post(url, data, headers){
  return this.http.post(`${this.baseURL}${url}`, data, { headers: new HttpHeaders(headers) } )
}

get(url, headers){
  return this.http.get(`${this.baseURL}${url}`, { headers: new HttpHeaders(headers) } )
}

delete(url,headers){
  return this.http.delete(`${this.baseURL}${url}`, { headers: new HttpHeaders(headers) } )
}

put(url, data, headers){
  return this.http.put(`${this.baseURL}${url}`, data, { headers: new HttpHeaders(headers) } )
}
```

I got this errors:

> Parameter 'url' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)

> Parameter 'data' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)

> Parameter 'headers' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)

How do I get this resolved?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create an interface or type in the type of url you're expecting for (if it's a url its probably a string). For example:

```
export interface IUrl{
...
}
```

then make the change the function parameters list;

```
post(url:IUrl ,...){
...
}
```

or

```
post(url:string ,...){
...
}
```

or as a second way (I don't suggest you to do it in that way), you can declare your input argument as declared any type explicity:

```
post(url:any ,...){
...
}
```